# Is any way to check requested ajax call is coming from akamai cache or latest data with cache?

Tags: ajax, performance, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, akamai

There is one URL which seems to returning cache response but we are not able identify Is its cache or latest data response?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Pragma headers (https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/Using-Akamai-Pragma-headers-to-investigate-or-troubleshoot-Akamai-content-delivery?language=en_US). Akamai will return information as to whether it was served from cache or origin.